# ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at accounts.google.com

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using a google authentication based on the following example. Everything was working and then suddendly when I tried to login I started getting  this error:

> httplib2.ServerNotFoundError ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the
>   server at accounts.google.com

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

```
    from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_oauth import OAuth


# You must configure these 3 values from Google APIs console
# https://code.google.com/apis/console
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = '<Client-ID>'
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = '<Client-secret>'
REDIRECT_URI = '/authorized'  # one of the Redirect URIs from Google APIs console

SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
DEBUG = True

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = DEBUG
app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY
oauth = OAuth()

google = oauth.remote_app('google',
                          base_url='https://www.google.com/accounts/',
                          authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
                          request_token_url=None,
                          request_token_params={'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                                                'response_type': 'code'},
                          access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
                          access_token_method='POST',
                          access_token_params={'grant_type': 'authorization_code'},
                          consumer_key=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                          consumer_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    access_token = session.get('access_token')
    if access_token is None:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    access_token = access_token[0]
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError

    headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth '+access_token}
    req = Request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo',
                  None, headers)
    try:
        res = urlopen(req)
    except URLError, e:
        if e.code == 401:
            # Unauthorized - bad token
            session.pop('access_token', None)
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        return res.read()

    return res.read()


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    callback=url_for('authorized', _external=True)
    return google.authorize(callback=callback)



@app.route(REDIRECT_URI)
@google.authorized_handler
def authorized(resp):
    access_token = resp['access_token']
    session['access_token'] = access_token, ''
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@google.tokengetter
def get_access_token():
    return session.get('access_token')


def main():
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before and the fix was to disable IPv6 on my computer. For some reason Google and IPv6 don't play well together.

If you're on a Mac, the command is:

```
sudo networksetup -setv6off wi-fi
```

Make sure to turn it back on when you're done:

```
sudo networksetup -setv6automatic wi-fi
```